# Using launch4j after Jar Obfuscation with Proguard

Tags: java, javafx, exe, proguard, launch4j

I'm trying to publish my java program in .exe but when using launch4j after using Proguard it tells me that can't find the main class the exe generated successfully but doesn't work at all when try to run it through launch4j it tells me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: unable to determine Application class
at ri3o.certification.generator.main.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

[Launch4j after obfuscating jar file with Proguard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ZYf.png)

Note : The same problem happens with Jar2Exe can't find the main method how can i prevent Proguard from obfuscating The Main Method ?
if I tried without obfuscating the jar it works properly. So, What should I check?